# Flutter console output shows no exceptions, errors or other debug data

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling

I don't get any data in my console when the app runs into an exception/error.
For example

```
final Map<String, String> notification = Map.from(message['notification']);
```

run without problem, but when I wrapped it in a try-catch block i caught the following

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

Shouldn't things like these show in the log per default?

Comment: are you using Vscode ? maybe you need to chech Uncaught Exception ticks in side panel

Comment: I am using android studio. Maybe I should try disabling the merged Logcat/Run flutter option and just go with the old Logcat. I'll update you If it solves the problem.